# How can I run Javascript on Django without exposing static files?

Tags: javascript, html, django, security, static

On my Django site, I used Stripe to integrate payments in a `.js` file.

I noticed that this file appears under Sources in the developer tools when you "Inspect Element" on any browser. Anyone can access this file (scary).

How can I restructure my file organization so that `apple-pay.js` is not public facing?

`home.html`

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    // Scripts for CSS and Stripe Pay
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        
       <div id="payment-request-button" data-amount="{{event.price}}" data-label=". 
          {{event.public_name}}">
                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here if the browser supports this type of payment method. -->
       </div>
       <div id="messages" role="alert"></div>

    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

`apple-pay.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => { 
    const stripe = Stripe('pk_mykeyishere'); //need to protect this information and the other functions from bad actors

    ///functions I run here
    
});
```

My file structure:

```
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── db.sqlite3
├── interface
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association
│   │   └── interface
│   │       ├── apple-pay.js <------------------
│   │       ├── CSS/other JS files
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── interface
│   │       ├── home.html <-------------------
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── AppName
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: If it's something that has to run in the browser, there's no way to guarantee that it won't be seen. You'd have to move it out of your public folder and otherwise not serve it, then process requests on its behalf if you want to run it server sde.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide JavaScript code from browser users, you can only minify and/or obscure it to make it harder for people to read and understand.

Stripe integration does not require you to put sensitive data into any JavaScript file. You should use that data on the server-side.

Comment: When you say "put that data on the server-side", what does that mean? Do you just mean to put my secret key into an environment variable?"

Comment: Stripe gives you two keys, a secret and a publishable key. Yes, it is a good idea to keep the secret one in an environment variable on the server-side. The other one is a publishable key. There is no harm using that in your JS code.

Comment: Could it be harmful that they can see the scripts I use to make calls to Stripe if my key is an environment variable?

Comment: You don't make calls by using the "scripts" (I guess you mean JavaScript). You need to use Python code on the server side to do the calls. That code will use your secret key in the environment variable. They won't see that code.

Comment: I think I mostly follow. Not sure how familiar you are with Django, but when you say server side is that a file I would just have in my Django project, or do I need to configure some script that would make API Calls hosted on some site? For context my site is hosted on Heroku.

Comment: @bernardo It should be a view in Django, to which you make a POST request from your page ad receive a response.